# Split Array object into chucks

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have this array in JS

```
initialArray = [A,B,C,C,D,E,F,F,G,K]
```

I want to split into:

```
chucks = [[A,B,C], [C,D,E,F], [F,G,K]]
```

Duplicate items are separators such as 'C' or 'F'

How to do this split in ES6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reduce the array and add either the value or a new array, depending on the last value.

```js
const
    array = ['A','B','C','C','D','E','F','F','G','K'],
    result = array.reduce((r, v, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => {
        if (v === last) r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(v);
        return r;
    }, [[]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @LongDang, please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: now is based on clones

```js
const initialArray = ["A","B","C","C","D","E","F","F","G","K"];
const chunks = [];
let smallChunk = [];

let index = 0;

while (index < initialArray.length){
  smallChunk.push(initialArray[index]);
  
  if (initialArray[index+1] == initialArray[index]){
    chunks.push(smallChunk);
    smallChunk = [];
  }
  
  index++;
}

chunks.push(smallChunk);
console.log(chunks);
```

Comment: No, Your solution is based on the size of the chunk. But in my case, the separator is the DUPLICATED item in initialArray,

Comment: @LongDang check it out, now it's based on clones

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straight forward solution using a single `for` loop and holding the current chunk in a variable to push to.

```js
const initialArray = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'K', 'K'];

const chunk_at_duplicate = (arr) => {
  let chunk = [], res = [chunk];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === arr[i - 1]) {
      res.push(chunk = []);
    }

    chunk.push(arr[i]);
  }

  return res;
};

console.log(chunk_at_duplicate(initialArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for ... of` together with `initialArray.entries()` as follows:

```js
const initialArray = ["A","B","C","C","D","E","F","F","G","K"];

const chunks = [];
let start = 0
for(const [i,v] of initialArray.entries()) {
    if(i > 0 && v === initialArray[i-1]) {
        chunks.push( initialArray.slice(start,i) );
        start = i;
    } else if( i === initialArray.length - 1 ) {
        chunks.push( initialArray.slice(start) );
    }
}

console.log( chunks );
```

Comment: You can simply use [`initialArray.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) which will return an iterator with integer indexes.

Comment: Yes indeed! Thank you @pilchard.